# Can I block all IPv6 traffic if I'm not using it/planning to use it?

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, ipv6

I'm setting up a CentOS server and I have no intention to use IPv6 on it by now. Because of this, I have a few simple questions:

- Is there any problem in blocking all IPv6 traffic on this machine (in and out)?
- If not, how can I accomplish it?

Thanks,

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't.  Dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/60481/how-to-completely-disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-9-04 anyway.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you don't have an IPv6 upstream IPv6 traffic is not going to be going out your connection regardless.

Comment: Without additional work you probably don't have a global IPv6 routable address so the issue is moot.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I'd block it; I think I would just disable the ipv6 stack.

http://www.vincentverhagen.nl/2007/06/22/disable-ipv6-on-red-hat/

Answer (score 0):

you can either disable it in the config scripts or use `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` to totally turn it off in the kernel.

Nonetheless... if you won't actually *have* IPv6 connectivity, I would argue it's not worth the effort.